# Display 'service' variable in react native component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to react-native coming from Angular.

I have class which is globally available in my app - equivalent to an an Angular service. It handles the connection to a bluetooth device.

```
import {BleManager} from "react-native-ble-plx";

class BleConnector {
    static bleManager = new BleManager();
    static connected = false;

    static connect() {
        // do stuff
        this.connected = true;
    }

}

export {BleConnector};
export default BleConnector;
```

Somewhere in my application I am calling the method to connect to the bluetooth device. I would like to visualize the state `BLeConnector.connected` in a react native component.

```
import {BLeConnector} from "BLeConnector"

export class HelloWorld extends Component {
    styles = mergeNativeStyles(defaultStyle, this.props.style);

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={this.styles.container}>
                <Text style={this.styles.label}>{BLeConnector.connected? "connected" : "disconnected"}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

The issue is that even through the `BLeconnector.connected` is changing to `true`, the component does not seem to rerender.
I understand that there is no two way binding in React - which coming from Angular seems like a huge downside - but I'm not able to find the solution on how to display the up-to-date status in the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a state management library like redux, zustand, recoil, etc.

Here's a simple example with [zustand](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand).

```
import create from 'zustand';

const useBleStore = create((set) => ({
  connected: false,
  onConnect: () => set({ connected: true }),
  onDisconnect: () => set({ connected: false }),
}))

function HelloWorld() {
  const connected = useBleStore((state) => state.connected)

  return (
    <View>
        <Text>{connected ? "connected" : "disconnected"}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: is the useBleStore maintained on the BLeConnector or on the component?

Comment: you can keep it in BleConnector or in a separate file, and import to all components who needs it.